# Load content of Navigation drawer item and ViewPagerStrip item on same container - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am developing an application, It has an Activity(MainActivity.java) ,I integrated Navigation Drawer over it ,when I click navigation drawer item then the content of navigation drawer item loads on the `<framelayout />` ,after that I integrated tabs at bottom on the same page (MainActivity.java) using ViewPagerStrip ,Now Problem is that :

> When I click on Navigation drawer item and tabs item the content of Navigation Drawer item and ViewPagerStrip item is not being loaded on the same container ,How can I load content of both (tabs item and drawer item ) on the same container (Framelayout or ViewPager) .

I have following code in MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Set activity_main.xml 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Create tabs at bottom using ViewPagerStrip 
        mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);

        //Create NavigationDrawer .
        ---------------------------------------
        ---------------------------------------
        ---------------------------------------
        }

//Click on Drawer menus
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayDrawerItem(position);
        }
    }

private void displayDrawerItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;

        //Other fragments goes here .

        default:
            break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
}
```

I have following code in my activity_main.xml

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#33b5e5"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</FrameLayout>

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**My own efforts**

I tried to solve this problem with different-2 approaches

> 1 . I put `<ViewPager  >` inside `<framelayout >` and tried to load click events of navigation item and tabs item on the ViewPager .
>   2 . I removed `<framelayout >` and tried to load click events of navigation and tabs items both on the ViewPager .
>   3 . I follow many Stackoverflow links ,tutorials regarding ViewPagerStrip and DrawerLayout , tried to search how to load click events of drawer item and tabs item on the same container .

**Edit**

```
    public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
Context mContext;
private String[] tabs = {"Trails", "Breweries", "Near By", "Events"};
public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Context context) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {

    // Create fragment object
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = new DemoFragment();

    // Attach some data to the fragment
    // that we'll use to populate our fragment layouts
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("page_name", tabs[position]);

    // Set the arguments on the fragment
    // that will be fetched in the
    // DemoFragment@onCreateView
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabs.length;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabs[position];
}}


public class DemoFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout resource that'll be returned
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab, container, false);

    // Get the arguments that was supplied when
    // the fragment was instantiated in the
    // CustomPagerAdapter
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(args.getString("page_name"));

    return rootView;
}}
```

Comment: How can I load content of both (tabs item and drawer item ) on the same container=>do you mean when you use both they are not displaying?

Comment: @Harry It displays content of tab only .

Comment: Then also show your CustomPagerAdapter.

Comment: @Harry I have Edited the question with CustomPageAdapter .

Comment: It displays content of tab only=>tabs are not coming or the navigation drawer?

Comment: @Haryy Tabs and navigation drawer booth are coming , but when I click on tab item then its corresponding fragment loads on ViewPager but it is not the case with navigation items their corresponding fragment is not being loaded .I want the same case with both type of items ,they should be load and should be visible independently on the same container .

Comment: Do you mean that if 2nd item selected from nav, it should select 2nd item from tabs pager? As you are replacing content of frame_container it wont get tabs again.

Comment: I don't mean this ,I mean when I click on nav item then it corresponding fragment should display ,and when I click on tab item then its corresponding fragment should display .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See xml layout below:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
                android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="#33b5e5"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
            android:visibility="gone"></FrameLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here when you click to tab set the frame_container visibility **gone** and when you click  on navigation drawer item make the frame_container visibility **visible**.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Here ,I don't want sliding tabs so how can I make them fixed tabs .

Comment: You should not ask other functionality than your question, still look at [Adding tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#tabs)

Comment: Okay..There is a problem I am getting with this code ,when I click on tabs item then it is being pasted over framelayout but it is not replacing previous content, it looks weired.